# Magento 1.9 update street adress line 2 via PHP

Tags: magento-1.9, php, customer-address, street-address

I'm writing some codes to update customer address using php, but the site use 2 street fields,

when i set it like  `$address->setStreet1('test 1');` it's not working `$address->setStreet('test 1');` ads only first field

[image]

EX-

```
$customerId = 1300;
$addressId = 920;

$customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($customerId);
$address = $customer->getAddressById($addressId);
$address->setStreet('123 Main Street');
$address->setCity('Anytown');
$address->save();
```

anyone know how to fix this or other solution for set the street of existing address

Answer (score 1):

to update Street1 and Street2 fields you just need to provide an array:

```
$address->setStreet(['123 Main Street', 'Street 2']);
```